# 100% Page Height w/ Scrollable Columns

Tags: html, css

I'm building a SPA that has a three column layout as shown below. The header is fixed. The columns are wrapped in a container with a height of 100%. Each of the columns need to become scrollable if content goes beyond the fold.

[image]

My basic HTML

```
<div class="fixed-header"></div>
    <div class=" page-container">
    <div class="left-panel"></div>
    <div class="content-area"></div>
    <div class="right-panel"></div>
</div>
```

The container CSS

```
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 4.25rem;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

The problem I'm having is if any panel is set to overflow: auto, it will scroll, but only when content is way off the page. I don't understand why this is occurring and I'm having no luck correcting it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried out css-grid so far? It's way more robust for layouting.

Comment: When you use `position: relative`, the content will be moved by the top-value. that mean, the bottom-edge is at 100% + 4.25rem in your case.

Comment: Thanks Steven. That's what I needed. Made some adjustments to take that 4.25rem into account and works well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the container occupy `100%` of the page, you'll want to make use of the **[viewport-relative unit `vh`](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)**. You'll want to combine this with **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** in order to compensate for the **[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)** offset.

As for the allowing the child elements to scroll vertically when there's too much content, you can simply apply **[`overflow-y: scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)** to them.

This can be seen in the following example
(click `Run code snippet` then `Full page` in order to see the heights taking effect at a larger size):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 4.25rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 4.25rem);
  display: flex;
}

.page-container>div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.left-panel {
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
}

.content-area {
  width: 40%;
  background: blue;
}

.right-panel {
  width: 30%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header"></div>
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="left-panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur mauris est, posuere non leo eget, finibus pharetra dui. Duis pellentesque libero sed risus rhoncus, id porttitor mi vehicula. Morbi auctor augue at metus rhoncus, sed semper lacus sollicitudin.
    Etiam sit amet ante lorem. Maecenas et commodo elit. Nullam sit amet vehicula est. Curabitur porttitor erat eros, vitae ornare ipsum eleifend vel. In nec nulla commodo ex pellentesque dictum vel in augue.</div>
  <div class="content-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur mauris est, posuere non leo eget, finibus pharetra dui. Duis pellentesque libero sed risus rhoncus, id porttitor mi vehicula. Morbi auctor augue at metus rhoncus, sed semper lacus sollicitudin.
    Etiam sit amet ante lorem. Maecenas et commodo elit. Nullam sit amet vehicula est. Curabitur porttitor erat eros, vitae ornare ipsum eleifend vel. In nec nulla commodo ex pellentesque dictum vel in augue.</div>
  <div class="right-panel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur mauris est, posuere non leo eget, finibus pharetra dui. Duis pellentesque libero sed risus rhoncus, id porttitor mi vehicula. Morbi auctor augue at metus rhoncus, sed semper lacus sollicitudin.
    Etiam sit amet ante lorem. Maecenas et commodo elit. Nullam sit amet vehicula est. Curabitur porttitor erat eros, vitae ornare ipsum eleifend vel. In nec nulla commodo ex pellentesque dictum vel in augue.</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!